# make local copy of list and mutate it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, copy

I have this code that takes in user integer inputs and only include a single copy of the number in a list. e.g.

in my code instead of making a new list in the second function and returning it, I need to make a local copy of the initial list and mutate it to include only a single occurrence of the integers. I'm not sure how to do that.

```
def listOfIntegerInput ():
    inputSeq = input("Please enter a space-separated sequence of integers: ")
    integerList= []
    inputSeq = inputSeq.split()
    for entry in inputSeq:
        try:
            integerList.append(int(entry))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return integerList

def uniqueInts (ListOfValues):
    uniqueInts = []
    for entry in ListOfValues:
        if entry not in uniqueInts:
            uniqueInts.append(entry)
    return uniqueInts



print("This program removes duplicates from a given sequence of integers")
inputSequence = listOfIntegerInput()
finalListOfUniqueInts = uniqueInts(inputSequence)
print(finalListOfUniqueInts)
```

output:

```
This program removes duplicates from a given sequence of integers
Please enter a space-separated sequence of integers: 1 1 2 3 4 5 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

so I only need to modify my second function `unqiueInts (listOfValues)` to modify the list but not return a list. I'm not sure how to  make a local copy and modify it.

so in essence, the final list should be the same object that was generated by the first function, only it would have been mutated/modified by the second function. The main program then prints that final list.

---

@JonClements

This what I have achieved by using the copy function. is this correct, or is there redundant code or better way (given that the code has to follow the algorithm of `if not in…`?

in the rules of the assignment, it says I need to rebuilt the initial argument from scratch in the second function ( "To implement the same algorithm, the argument list should be rebuilt from scratch i.e. has to be emptied and its (unique) elements added one by one, and thus, a local copy of the initial list has to be made beforehand.")

```
def listOfIntegerInput():
    inputSeq = input("Please enter a space-separated sequence of integers: ")
    integerList = []
    inputSeq = inputSeq.split()
    for entry in inputSeq:
        try:
            integerList.append(int(entry))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return integerList


def uniqueInts(ListOfValues):
    CopyOfListOfValues = ListOfValues[:]
    ListOfValues.clear()
    for entry in CopyOfListOfValues:
        if entry not in ListOfValues:
            ListOfValues.append(entry)


print("This program removes duplicates from a given sequence of integers")
inputSequence = listOfIntegerInput()
uniqueInts(inputSequence)
print(inputSequence)
```

Comment: To make a copy of a list do `copy = lst[:]`, where `lst` is the original list and  `copy` is the copy of `lst`.

Comment: @thornejosh would this be added under the second function?

Comment: Check out built-in python's set if order of elements is not important. It's not related to the question, but using list(set(input_sequence)) will give the same result except for ordering. Also note that Python formatting guide (search for such PEP, if you are interested) recommends using under_scores for variables and functions, not camelCase.

Comment: @MANNY are you wanting to remove consecutive duplicates or all duplicates? eg: would `[1, 2, 1]` remain `[1, 2, 1]` or would that also become `[1, 2]` ?

Comment: Having said... if your second function is meant to mutate the passed in list, and not return anything, then you can instead of `return uniqueInts`, do: `ListOfValues[:] = uniqueInts` as the final line of your second function... then you'll see the changes reflected in `inputSequece`... is that what you're after?

Comment: @JonClements it should remove all duplicates. I have modified the code and made a copy as you and @thornejosh suggested, and did ```ListOfValues.clear()``` and saw the output reflects in ```inputSequence``` is that a correct way? I can post the new code in the answers section if want to see?

Comment: @СтаниславТерляков unfortunately I'm unable to use ```set``` of ```list.remove()``` functions and have to follow the format of the code given which is the same as in my code except a few extras